# Can you help on a question about measurable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question: Let $\alpha \geq 0$ be a step function. Let $\beta = a \chi_A + b\chi_B$ where $a,b > 0$, $A \ and \ B$ are disjoint and measurable sets Show that $\alpha \wedge\beta = (\alpha \wedge a)\chi_A + (\alpha \wedge b) \chi_B$.

Now $\chi_A$ and $\chi_B$ are indicator functions. I know that $\alpha \wedge \beta = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta - |\alpha -\beta|)$. I am not sure what else to do here. Is there some sort of trick to use? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,

If we start with intuition, you can see that $\alpha$ being a step function, it can be seen as a sum of indicator functions 
$$ \alpha  = \sum \alpha_i \chi_{S_i}  $$ 
and therefore only takes positive values over the union of $ S_i $ subsets.

So now, applying the "and" operator $ \wedge$ over $\alpha $ and $\beta$ implies that the result will only have positive values where both terms are non-negative.

Now, doing some computations : 
\begin{align}
\alpha \wedge \beta & = \alpha \wedge ( a \chi_A + b \chi_B ) \\
 & = \alpha \wedge (a \chi_A) + \alpha \wedge (b \chi_B) \\
 & = ( \alpha \wedge a ) \chi_A + ( \alpha \wedge b ) \chi_B
\end{align}

The last line is implied by the fact that $ \alpha \wedge (a \chi_A) $ is different of $0$ if and only if we are at the intersection of the support of $\alpha$ and $A$, which is equivalent to $ ( \alpha \wedge a ) \chi_A $ since that, if we are out of the union of $S_i $ , $\alpha = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha \wedge a = 0 \Rightarrow ( \alpha \wedge a ) \chi_A = 0 $. To have equivalence, you can easily guess that if we are out of $A$,$( \alpha \wedge a ) \chi_A = 0 $.

However, depending on the context in which you have to proove this, you might have to detail all subsequent cases.

Comment: Okay. This makes sense. I have another question.  So if $\alpha$ is a step function and $\beta$ is a simple function, is it true that $\alpha \wedge \beta $ is a step function?

Comment: Of course, since $ \alpha \wedge \beta $ can only be non-negative if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are. 
You can even write $ \alpha \wedge \beta = \sum_i (\alpha_i \beta) \chi_{S_i} $

Comment: That's what I got! Thank's a lot! Stay safe!

Comment: Is it okay I can ask you one more question?